# What exactly is type void and how does it work?

Tags: c, pointers, types, void, void-pointers

I've almost completed my C Primer Plus book and I'm about to hit Structures and Unions, etc... etc..., but I still don't have a full grasp of what exactly the keyword void is. What does void do? How does it work? And when should I use it?

i understand that

```
void function(void)
```

basically says that there is no return value. there are no arguments.
i know that you can use different scenarios,

```
int function(void); //has a return of type int -- voids args
void function(int); //voids return type -- takes type int as an arg
```

i also understand that

```
void * p = 0L;
```

is valid code and that it's basically a pointer-to-void with the initialized value of 0 long.

but is there any value or purpose to using it in such a way

```
void k = 0;
```

or am i just voiding the data type? and if so, is there any usefulness to voiding a data type?
because from what i've been able to infer, it's very useful in functions and pointers for working
with an undefinable data type such as

```
size_t fwrite(const void * restrict ptr, ...more args...);
```

since the first argument is not a fixed type, my book describes this as being a "catchall type for pointers" and that "Pre-ANSI C uses type *char ** for this argument, which requires you to typecast actual arguments to that type".

Does this mean that I can use **any** data type? 
And if so, is this restricted to pointers and functions **only**?

Again... I'm not concerned with how to convert a int to void. I'm not concerned with is a pointer-to-void valid, but merely on how to effectively use this keyword. I'm concerned with "When should I use it?" and "How should I use it?".

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there any value or purpose to using it in such a way
>
> `void k = 0;`

No, that statement doesn't make any sense, and the compiler will complain about an incomplete type. Notice that whenever you see `void` used in a type declaration, it's followed by a `*` that indicates a pointer, like:

```
void *foo = nil;
```

In that case, you're telling the compiler that `foo` is a pointer, which is really all it needs to know in order to create `foo`. Without the `*`, you're trying to declare a variable that has no type, and that's not something that a compiler (or a human, for that matter) can work with.

> since the first argument is not a fixed type, my book describes this as being a "catchall type for pointers"

The first argument *is* a "fixed type" -- the type is a pointer. It's true that the type that the pointer points to is unspecified, but the parameter itself is a pointer.

> Does this mean that I can use any data type?

You can use a *pointer* to any type of data. `fwrite()` takes a pointer to an array of some type of object, along with the size of that type, the number of objects, and a pointer to a file, and it writes those objects to the file. `fwrite()` doesn't care about the type of the objects, but since it doesn't have any type information you need to explicitly pass the size and number.

Comment: thank you. my book didnt go in to much detail. this helps clarify some missing details from my understanding in what was potentially occurring with these data types. also it helps to be reminded that a pointer is a type, which is something that keeps slipping from my memory. thanks for helping out a C newcomer. This is my first "real programming langauge" and im trying to understand as much of the basic concepts as i can as I progress further in to my studies.

Answer (score 3):

There are three basic situations where the `void` type is used. There might be some other marginal situations, but these three are where you'll see `void` used, maybe 99% of the time.

It helps to understand this by keeping in mind that "void" means "there is no type here", as in "datatype".

1) Declare a function that returns no value, as opposed to a function that returns some value.

2) Declare a function that takes no parameters, as opposed to a funciton that takes one or more parameters.

3) The "pointer to void" situation.

The third case basically defines a generic pointer. A pointer to ...something, but this "something" is not important in the section of code that deals with the pointer.

For example, here's manual page for the `memcpy` function():

```
MEMCPY(3)                  Linux Programmer's Manual                 MEMCPY(3)

NAME
       memcpy - copy memory area

SYNOPSIS
       #include <string.h>

       void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);

DESCRIPTION
       The  memcpy()  function  copies  n bytes from memory area src to memory
       area dest.  The memory areas must not overlap.  Use memmove(3)  if  the
       memory areas do overlap.
```

You can read the rest of the manual page yourself. memcpy() takes a couple of pointers that specify a block of memory to be copied around. memcpy() doesn't care what the pointers point to. It doesn't need to know that, so it's function prototype specifies that any pointer can be passed to it. A point to an `int`, a pointer to a `char`, or a pointer to some class instance.

Comment: thank you. this helped clarify what caleb said above.